# Is C.G. Jung considered a respectable philosopher by professional philosophers?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy

I thought he was mainly a philosopher since his theories are mostly philosophical (or at best quasi scientific).
Since he is rarely cited by philosophers it makes me wonder if he is considered a  serious philosopher by researching philsophers?

Comment: Is Descartes "primarily" a philosopher or "primarily" a scientist/mathematician? What matters to philosophers is that he was, in particular, a philosopher. Who he was "primarily" is more of a question for biographers. Jung (like Freud) arguably focused more on psychology and psychiatry, that was his day job. He certainly philosophized, but mostly on related issues, which is a niche topic in philosophy, so philosophers would only cite him when that is what they are researching, see [Jung and Philosophy](https://books.google.com/books/about/Jung_and_Philosophy.html?id=iJaTDwAAQBAJ).

Comment: @Conifold Isn't most of his work on the philosophy of psychology/psychiatry ? I have read very little of his work but it kind of gives me the impression that he thought he created some sort "algebra of the psyche" that later psychologists/philosophers  would sort it's details out. It seems to me that  later on his theories were mostly abandoned since most of the later researchers depending on their ability either found them too difficult/abstract to be able to decode and extend them or trivial/dubious to be useful to them.

Comment: The boundary between theoretical psychology and applied philosophy of psychology is vague, and was especially in his time. Like Freud, he thought he was mapping unconscious psychological structures, and he branched out into other areas of philosophy even less than Freud. Some of his conceptions, like collective unconscious and archetypes, are philosophically current, and there is a revival of interest in others, as the linked volume indicates. It is fair to say that to date he was not as much explored by philosophers as Freud or Fromm, especially on the analytic side.

Comment: See [Carl Gustav Jung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Jung#Thought): "was a Swiss psychiatrist and psychoanalyst who founded analytical psychology. Jung's work was influential in the fields of psychiatry, anthropology, archaeology, literature, philosophy, and religious studies. Although he was a practicing clinician and writer and as such founded analytical psychology, much of his life's work was spent exploring related areas such as physics, vitalism, Eastern and Western philosophy, alchemy, astrology, and sociology, as well as literature and the arts.  1/2

Comment: Jung's interest in philosophy and spiritual subjects led many to view him as a mystic, although his preference was to be seen as a man of science." 2/2